# Trouble adding leading zeroes to submitted form data in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I looked through here last night for some examples on adding leading zeroes with JavaScript and I couldn't get any of them to work for my purposes.  I want to do this with the data once you hit the submit button.  It is running a set of checkers when it does this and this is what I have included, but I grab the POST data in a test php page and the field I am trying to fix shows "undefined"

I need the number of digits to always be 7, regardless of whether they entered a four or five digit number.  Leading zeroes need to be added.  Not sure if I am kind of close or way off target with this:

```
function pad(number, length){
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }    
}

offidlength = custform.optionaldata10.value.length;

if (offidlength <7) {
    custform.optionaldata10.value = pad(custform.optionaldata10.value, 7);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `return` statement.

```
return str;
```

Should be at the end of the function.

*edit* function should look like:

```
function pad(number, length){
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
       str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;    
}
```

Comment: No way!  Is that it?  ::facepalm::

Comment: Hmmm That fixed the undefined (can't believe I missed that) but its not adding multiple zeroes, just one zero.

Comment: @red6 make sure the `return` is in the function but **outside** the `while` loop `{` `}` or else it'll quit after the first 0.

Comment: Thanks!  The real shame here is that I cannot even upvote your reply because I haven't been here long enough.  Was teaching myself this stuff 6 months ago and then left it and now shaking off the rust, so I am missing some of the obvious things apparently.  Thanks for the assist, it works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your expression simpler, if you always want 7 digits-

```
var offid= custform.optionaldata10.value, L= 7-offid.length;
if(L>0) custform.optionaldata10.value= '0000000'.substring(0, L)+offid;
```